# Is there a way to close modal video/pdf view on mobile screen

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using modal(ant design) to show video and pdf view on a mobile screen. When I click on the back button of mobile video/pdf view plus main screen is getting closed, I only want to close video/pdf view and modal that's it not the main screen.

Kindly suggest how can I achieve this.

Comment: I haven't used ant design, but in your scenario, is it not possible to open the video/pdf in a new window?

Comment: currently not possible to do that

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative 1:**

You need to capture the browsers back button event, and make that event set the `<Modal visible={}/>` state variable to close the modal, instead of actually navigating back.

How to capture the back event depends on what type of routing you are using.

For the NextJS router you can register an `beforeHistoryChange` [event listener](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerevents).

**Alternative 2:**

Add a URL parameter to the page that controls the modal open state. So you have `<Modal visible={router.query.modal !== undefined} ... />`.

Then if you open the modal from `/page` the URL becomes for example `/page?modal=open`.

And if the user presses back the browser goes back to `/page` and the modal closes.